# Mysql JPA throws javax.transaction.RollbackException: instead of ConstraintViolationException

Tags: jpa, jboss7.x

I am using Mysql & JPA on Jobss7.1 for astruts2 based application.
I use user transaction not CMT.
I would like to catch ConstraintViolationException when I insert a duplicate row into the table

the below code catches the javax.transaction.RollbackException but not ConstraintViolationException

```
            try {
                  userdao=new UserDaoImpl();
                  InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
                  UserTransaction  utx = (UserTransaction) ic.lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
                  utx.begin();
                  userdao.setEm(em);
                  userdao.saveConatact(contact);
                  userdao.saveUser(user);
                  utx.commit();
                  return SUCCESS;
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
              e.printStackTrace();
              return ERROR;
            }

        org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'john' for key 'PRIMARY'
            at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1361) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
            at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1289) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
            at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1295) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
            at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$CallbackExceptionMapperImpl.mapManagedFlushFailure(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1481) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
            at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.java:109) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
            at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:53) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:76)
            at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:273)
            at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:93)
            at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:164)
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1165)
            at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:117)
            at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75)
            at org.jboss.tm.usertx.client.ServerVMClientUserTransaction.commit(ServerVMClientUserTransaction.java:167)
            at com.action.RegistrationAction.createUser(RegistrationAction.java:66) [classes:]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:254) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:254) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:139) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
            at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
            at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
        Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'john' for key 'PRIMARY'
            at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:74) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
            at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:56) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
            at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2849) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
            at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3290) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
            at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:80) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
            at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:272) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
            at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:264) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
            at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:186) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
            at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
            at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
            at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1081) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
            at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:315) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
            at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.java:104) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
            ... 79 more
        Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'john' for key 'PRIMARY'
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
            at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:971)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2530)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1907)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2141)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2077)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2062)
            at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:493)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
            ... 93 more
```

Comment: Invoking the UserTransaction’s setRollbackOnly() will cause it to throw javax.transaction.RollbackException. What you need to do is separate each try in a new transaction

Comment: it is not throwing exception while em.perist(). but while committing utx.commit()

Comment: Your JPA provider (or JTA provider) may throw javax.transaction exceptions, but not MySQL. Obviously if you posted the exception and its stack trace then we could all see (including the nested exceptions)